# Selenium Web Driver - Generic find_by() method?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to port some Selenium written for Selenium Remote Control to use the Seleneium Web Driver, by re-exporting from the IDE to Python Web Driver format (instead of the python remote control format) Many of the locators are just bare locators, rather than specifying if it's an id/name/css/xpath/etc. Selenium Remote Control (& IDE) would just try each method until it worked.

However the python web driver export doens't like this, and fills each line with:

```
# ERROR: Caught exception [Error: locator strategy either id or name must be specified explicitly.]
```

Is there any `find_by_anything(locator)`  approach for selenium web driver? I don't care about speed, just functionality.

Comment: There is, but they are private methods. The `By` objects used throughout are meant to represent an abstraction of finding mechanisms. So it exists, but it's deep within the framework which is hidden by the various `find_elements_by_xxxxx` methods. Remember Selenium is totally open source so here's a direct link for what I'm talking about: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L664 (I assume it's a "private" method from the comments but haven't actually tried it)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is NO.

There is no method in Selenium which can take any kind of locator and give the web element for you. It should be either by id, class, xpath, css selector or etc..

You could create a new method and have that do the work for you. Proboablably like below.

The below java method that I created on my own which can accept any kind of By object.

```
public WebElement findElement(By obj){
   return driver.findElement(obj);
}
```

Comment: He's using python.  The `find_element_by_SELECTOR` are explicit, there isn't a generic `findElement` that accepts an argument of type `By`.  Or at least, per Arran, one that is publicly accessible.

Comment: I meant to have this create an equivalent function name that I provided in Java.. I chose findElement.. but he can name on his own.. Hope I make sense.

Comment: sure, there is a find_element(by='id', value=None)